# print when expression to display Static text if there is atleast a not null field in a detail band

Tags: jasper-reports, expression

I want to put a printWhenExpression on a static text based on a condition which says that print the label only if there is atleast a non null textField in a particular column in detail band.

Its like print the column header only if there is a non null field in that column.

I tried putting this expression: `$F{textfield} != null`, but it works only for first record, if first record has null and second record has not null value then the label will be hidden, where as we want it to be displayed.

Please reply if you need any more info.

The below is my .jrxml file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="IdpPdfSignature1" pageWidth="296" pageHeight="300" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="296" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="1c6e4be1-891b-4d0e-abfd-1c17f663d5be">
    <property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"/>
    <import value="java.util.*"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*"/>
    <parameter name="mypic" class="java.io.InputStream" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="mypic1" class="java.io.InputStream" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="mypic2" class="java.io.InputStream" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="group" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="device" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="timeperiod" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="customStartDate" class="java.util.Date" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="customEndDate" class="java.util.Date" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="footer" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <field name="signatureID" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[signatureID]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="signatureClassification" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[signatureClassification]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="description" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[description]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="count" class="java.lang.Long">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[count]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="formattedCount" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="messageType" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="mypic" class="java.io.InputStream"/>
    <variable name="mypic1" class="java.io.InputStream"/>
    <variable name="mypic2" class="java.io.InputStream"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="16" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-2" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="160" height="16" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="967c915b-1af1-4972-805f-0e3f365ba11c">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{messageType}!=null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Signature Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-3" mode="Opaque" x="210" y="0" width="86" height="16" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="a998a72e-01fa-4c27-ad7e-1e3a6c3408d2"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Event Count]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-11" mode="Opaque" x="160" y="0" width="50" height="16" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="5170b4a6-3531-412d-9f8f-bc32dc4de0be">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{messageType}!=null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Type]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="16" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="textField-7" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="160" y="0" width="50" height="16" uuid="917d3aff-44a7-4a26-865a-d466aff3ab00">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{messageType}!=null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="5">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{messageType}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="textField" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="160" height="16" uuid="72492119-a45f-49c5-8fb8-19252c57e402">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{messageType}!=null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{signatureClassification}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="textField" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="210" y="0" width="86" height="16" uuid="223be44f-8565-40e3-9d43-0f13b4e159b7"/>
                <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{formattedCount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show/hide a column at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116053/how-to-show-hide-a-column-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Table Component to achieve this instead of using Static text by giving print when condition under "Column Print When" property of Table's column Header.

i.e. Column Print When = $F{messageType}!=null

***PFB corrected JRXML:***

```
<summary>

    <band height="55" splitType="Stretch">
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement uuid="632c8fad-e35f-4b89-b28e-b363b0711c06" x="0" y="0" width="270" height="55"/>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <datasetRun subDataset="Table Dataset 1" uuid="bf16282a-8672-46cb-9849-4966b5f8c969">
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(1)]]></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="00429e67-6d71-4b66-9eb4-22d0c649e7a4">
                    <jr:columnHeader height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="a62a81ca-ceae-4178-9e4e-6ca17fc89c69" key="staticText-2" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CCCCCC">
                                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{messageType}!=null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                            </reportElement>
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[Signature Name]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell height="20" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement uuid="cb654043-45a4-4742-86ed-ed9818716db2" key="textField" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20">
                                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{messageType}!=null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                            </reportElement>
                            <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="10">
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement>
                                <font fontName="Arial"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{signatureClassification}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="7ebf1fdd-52e5-43da-96f0-1c01a7cb0876">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{messageType}!=null]]></printWhenExpression>
                    <jr:columnHeader height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="d96cce84-1318-49aa-a6d2-3a17e4329ef3" key="staticText-11" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CCCCCC">
                                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{messageType}!=null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                            </reportElement>
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[Type]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell height="20" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement uuid="4832a90d-505e-4f13-87bf-0a7fe6e3a00f" key="textField-7" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20">
                                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{messageType}]]></printWhenExpression>
                            </reportElement>
                            <box leftPadding="5">
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                                <font fontName="Arial"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{messageType}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="89b50640-0509-4b61-8aa3-aa68eb3e6685">
                    <jr:columnHeader height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement uuid="fe68d8bf-3f0d-4202-a53c-8c6f328e4d16" key="staticText-3" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[Event Count]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell height="20" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement uuid="169af53a-b587-4d63-93f8-cb9296c89f4c" key="textField" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                            <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="10">
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#999999"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                                <font fontName="Arial"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{formattedCount}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</summary>
```

Hope this resolve your issue.

Regards,

Srikanth Kattam

Answer (score 0):

Using a variable set to 'Count' will allow you to check if the field contained at least one non-null value. As we can only know this after all the records have been processed we have to configured the evaluation time on our column header to 'Report' instead of now. Eval time can't be set on 'Static Text' but we can use a 'Text Field' instead. Also Eval time does not apply to 'Print When' expressions as the reports engine needs to know if we are drawing a element or not which we can't determine while we are still at the column header. Using a expression that results in null depending on the count variable solves this problem (using 'Blank When NULL').

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.19.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A45" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="81b8aa8f-65d7-4eec-b9de-322d7c5d185d">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="technotrix_dev"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT null as field1, null as field2
UNION ALL 
SELECT null as field1, 'foobar' as field2
UNION ALL 
SELECT null as field1, null as field2]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="field1" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="field1"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="field1"/>
    </field>
    <field name="field2" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="field2"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="field2"/>
    </field>
    <variable name="field1_count" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{field1}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="field2_count" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{field2}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="210" height="20" uuid="aaf98575-6e1e-4839-be84-b3bc37d14653">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="bf75b6ee-b46c-4aa6-9f57-d15a9c87f716"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{field1_count} > 0 ? "field1" : null]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="240" y="0" width="210" height="20" uuid="b6eba88b-e9c0-4b18-bf12-56944b2c55a1">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="bf75b6ee-b46c-4aa6-9f57-d15a9c87f716"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{field2_count} > 0 ? "field2" : null]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="17" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="12" uuid="6f8ce0e1-b4d1-4c3a-ab20-f57dda15fbab">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="bf75b6ee-b46c-4aa6-9f57-d15a9c87f716"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="240" y="0" width="100" height="12" uuid="06138904-09f2-4c1b-8218-3982416ebc7e">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="bf75b6ee-b46c-4aa6-9f57-d15a9c87f716"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
</detail>
```