# Jasper suppress column on bases of permision to user

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am new to jasper ,i have worked on suppressing columns on bases of configuration ,but is there a way ouy to suppress column of a report on the bases of user permission .

For example 
I have a user role Role_user which doesnt have permission to view the salary package of employee ,in a table containing column header such as Employee name,
Employee code, Employee Contact Number

can there any way to hide with permision

Comment: Is this question about JasperReports Server?

Comment: Yes its about jaaperreports server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show/hide a column at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116053/how-to-show-hide-a-column-at-runtime), this is the best indication I can give you, maybe you can build on it.

Comment: i have discovered it u can do it by using api to get userrole and username and manipulating according to the condition