# Jasper Reports - Adding Column to .jrxml at runtime

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a .jrxml file template generated and I am trying to create reports for different scenarios. In some cases, i have to add new columns to what is already present in the .jrxml file or I have to remove columns. Is there a way where I can still use the .jrxml as the base and add or remove a column programmatically?

Comment: What API are you using?

Comment: related if pure jrxml:  [How to show/hide a column at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116053/how-to-show-hide-a-column-at-runtime)